# Python Error: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars

Tags: python, scipy

I am running into the error in the title with the code below:

```py
from scipy import special as sp
def func(x, n):
coefs = [[0] * (n+1) for _ in range(n+1)]
for i in range(n+1):
        for j in range(i+1):
                if j <=x:
                        coefs[i][j] = sp.binom(i, j)
                else:
                        sumation = 0
                        for k in range(x+1):
                                sumation = sumation + coefs[i - k - 1][j - k]
                        coefs[i][j] = sumation
```

Running this with

```py
print(func(10, 1500))
```

returns the error:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
sum = sum + list[i - k - 1][j - k]
```

It works up until just past `n = 1000`.

I am using Python 3.6. I thought that numbers could be any size in this version of Python but I am new to it so I might just be missing something.

Any help with overcoming this would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: what is the value of `i`?

Comment: x < n

for i in range(n+1):
    for j in range(i+1):
        sum = 0
        for k in range(x+1):
            sum = sum + list[i - k - 1][j - k]

this is only called when i - k - 1 is in bounds and j - k are also in bounds, 100% sure of this

Comment: can you post the error message

Comment: and what is the value of `n`? what is `list`? please give [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). and update your post (by edit), not put in the comment section

Comment: All it gives me is

/mnt/c/Users/xxxxx/xxx/program.py:27: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
sum = sum + list[i - k - 1][j - k]

the number that gets returned is inf

Comment: i updated the post. im not on this site much i hope i provided enough

Comment: Is numpy somehow involved in the complete program?

Comment: it was originally but i got rid of it

Answer (score 0):

Some observations:  first, it runs on my machine without error; second, the `print(func(10, 1500))` call always prints `None` since `func()` doesn't return anything; third, it creates an 1501 by 1501 matrix-like structure but only operates on the first 11 elements of each row, leaving the last 1490 elements of each row set to 0 which seem odd, as if the index ranges aren't correct.

Fourth, you've redefined Python built-in function names as variables which isn't a good idea as you can't use them for their original purpose in the scope of your function:

```
>>> list
<class 'list'>
>>> sum
<built-in function sum>
>>>
```

Fifth, are you aware that one of these indexes:

```
sum = sum + list[i - k - 1][j - k]
```

is going negative at times:

```
sum = sum + list[10][-5]
```

so you're accessing this row from the left end (where all the zeros are.)

Sixth, now that you added a call to `sp.binom(i, j)`, it fails for me when I run it with the error in question.  Are you aware that `sp.binom()` returns a `numpy.float64` which can't size up like a Python integer.

I'm running Python 3.6.0 -- perhaps you could provide more information about your environment.

> I thought that numbers could be any size in this version of python

The last row of `list` is:

```
[1, 746, 185755, 23157624, 1736848299, 87162383901, 3138960008701, 85259372826713, 1813040043422321, 31075927633744029, 439493479567385970, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

So number size doesn't appear to be an issue.

Comment: I am also on python 3.6. (Also didn’t catch that I really only need the first x elements lol I’ll change that)

Comment: Not sure what else could be different. That exact code throws that error for me

Comment: @vinny, try renaming your `list` and `sum` variables to unique names to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: made these changes and it is still working, but it is failing still for the use case I really need, which I am updating in the OP right now

Comment: @vinny, I added another issue to my list regarding negative indexes.  And double check that the numpy stuff is really gone as this error message is most commonly associated with numpy.

Comment: yeah everything numpy is 100% gone. also i am quite drunk instead of if i <= x it should be if j <= x, which I think fixes that error. reflecting that in OP atm too. still getting same error

Comment: @vinny, see my additional sixth point about scipy, binom and numpy.  By not providing this code to begin with, I feel like you've lead me on a wild goose chase!

Comment: It still didn’t work for me in the original code I had though. And it isn’t working writing my own function to calculate factorial, so I am thinking more must be wrong :’(